# Recursively count all files ignoring certain directory paths

Tags: filesystem, tree, directory-structure

I want to recursively count all files contained in `root` ignoring all files contained in the following directory paths:

```
root/*/build
root/*/*/*/build
```

how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 find . -type f -not -path "*/build/*" | wc -l
```

This will recursively count all files, ignoring any directories containing a `build` folder.